# Set "advanced" FMU parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, fmi

I have implemented some FMUs via the FMI-Toolbox in my Simulink model. I'm currently trying to set the values from the "Advanced" tab in the FMU settings, in particular the sampling interval. From my understanding, the parameters and start values can be set via fmuSetValueSimulink(), but is it also possible to set the advanced values?

Thanks a lot!
Felix

Comment: I could not find the answer to your question in the documentation. 
As a workaround you can create a MATLAB workspace variable, e.g. sam_time and enter it in the Advance tab. The mask of the FMIT block is created with a callback_functions, which writes the entries to the S-Functions parameter list of the underlying S-Function that interfaces the FMU.
(Please tag this with FMIT, as this is FMI Toolbox by Modelon and not FMI or Simulink specific)

Comment: This works for me, thank you very much! Thanks for the advice regarding the tags as well, unfortunately I can't use create FMIT tag since my reputation is too low.